# How to pass parameter like "User[user]" as json string , while using the Restemplate?

Tags: java, spring, rest

How to  pass `payload/` Form parameters making as JSON object with some strings are like "User[user]", while using the Restemplate?

Comment: well, you create a json object with some online editor which also provide json validation. Then you try to use some browser extension something like "Restclient", and submit the request.

Comment: Can you clarify more about your requirement?

Comment: Hi Vignesh, My code is like

Comment: While passing payload as string it's working but when passing json object (request.toString ) gives un authorized. Could you please tell me where is the exact problem while parsing json to string.